# Variations of coloring problems with parity constaints

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, parity

I am looking for a variation of a graph colouring problem without the restriction that every two adjacent vertices have different colours (i.e. not a proper colouring), but instead with some parity constraints (like requiring an even number of neighbours of a specific colour). If someone came across such a problem, please let me know!

Thanks